# How to revert a changeset merged to another branch?

Tags: tfs

I  have check-in changes(ChangesetA) to Branch A. Then a merge happened from BranchA to BranchB. So now all changes including  ChangesetA in Branch B. How can I revert ChangesetA from Branch B. I there any easy method?

Answer (score 0):

**Rollback**

Rollback at the version previous at your checkin in Branch A(ChangesetA), protect the rollback and now merge with Branch B.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is rollbacking the changeset that has the merges to Branch B, and then reapply the merge without changeset A.

If you have some changesets after changeset A need to be include in Branch B. You could also do something like below: For example you changesetA ID=8 , now the latest changeset ID=15

- Rollback changeset 8 on  Branch and check-in. This will create
  changeset 16 on S Branch A
- Merge the changeset 8 to Branch-B
- Rollback changeset 16 on Branch-A branch and check-in which will
  create changeset 17 on Branch-A

In future merges to Branch-B from Branch-A skip merging changeset 17.

You could either use the [Rollback Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rollback-command-team-foundation-version-control) or through visual studio IDE. More details please refer this tutorial -- [Roll back changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/roll-back-changesets)